# Как работает plt.plot()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Я бы не засорял ресурс,но у меня непонимание.

```
plt.plot(range(-2,5), range(4,-3,-1)) - спокойно рисует линию
```

Играя с параметрами я **постоянно** получал ошибки.
Я так и не смог понять,почему не работает?
Сработало только с `plt.plot(range(-2,4), range(3,-3,-1))`
но с другими никак -

`plt.plot(range(-2,6), range(2,-3,-1))`

```
plt.plot(range(-3,6), range(4,-4,-1))
```

PS ошибка говорит,что x и y должны иметь оиднаковую размерность

```
plt.plot([2,4],[2,5])
```

Но здесь же размерность разная,почему тут работает?

НА ВОПРОС МОЖНО НЕ ОТВЕЧАТЬ,Я ПЕРЕОСМЫСЛИЛ СВОЙ ВОПРОС!

Comment: plt.plot([2,4],[2,5]) - где ж тут разная размерность? одинаковая она. Или вы не отличаете range от списка? Тогда учите матчасть. И вообще, у matplotlib полно документации, где английским по белому все хорошо написано.

Comment: @strawdog да, я понял свою ошибку. размерность списка p[2,4]-2, range(2,4)-тоже 2, я просто не понял почему изменение координаты x и y не может быть разное? допустим, за время(10 секунд) скорость увеличилась на 1 км/ч, а по логике plot() должно быть,что за 10 секунд скорость изменилась на 10 км/ч. Хотя не очень верно сравнивать, график зависимости и обычное рисование,все же думаю так вам будет понятнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что за аргументы вы передаете функцию? Это множество значений `X` и множество значений `Y` (а вместе это множество точек). Так как у каждой точки есть ровно 2 координаты, количество координат `X` и `Y` должно быть равным. А у вас оно отличается, поэтому и выдаётся ошибка.

Comment: можно я удалю вопрос? он оказался очень тупым))) я просто понял почему возникает проблема и причина очень смешная))))

Comment: @Тима удаляйте, если этого хотите. Власть над вопросом в ваших руках :)

Comment: Вы не можете удалить этот вопрос, так как другие участники потратили время и усилия, отвечая на него. Для получения дополнительной информации обратитесь к.  Ну ладно,будет уроком для меня,что лучше хорошенько подумать,даже если решение не кажется таким простым или явным))